# Access current_user / current_account context in a Rails Turbo Stream partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

So in my app I have the user and account info in the  stream: `web    | [ActionCable] [User 8] [Account 3] Turbo::StreamsChannel transmitting...`

Set here:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    include SetCurrentRequestDetails

    identified_by :current_user, :current_account, :true_user
    impersonates :user

    delegate :params, :session, to: :request

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      set_request_details
      self.current_account = Current.account

      logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}", "Account #{current_account.id}"
    end
end
```

The example would be a turbo based comments system.  New comments are pushed to all users on a given page  - the original poster and other users.  The poster can edit / destroy (via Pundit authorization) and the other users just view (i.e. hide / disable the actions).

When you append a partial via Turbo you can't just call `current_user` etc. as that fails.  You can do the trick to pass `current_user` into the broadcast but that is only the poster user ID.

If the logs are able to have access to the user and account can you that from inside the partial broadcast_append?:

```
broadcast_append_to [commentable, :comments], target: "comments", partial: "comments/comment", locals: { user: user }
```